# How to force inline-block wrap to new line using CSS or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have ten items. How do I make it to two lines, each having five items?

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    //...
    <li>item5</li>
    //newline
    <li>item6</li>
    <li>item10</li>
<ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li { display: inline-block; }
```

Note, I have to use `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

Comment: ul width/5 = li width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
$( "ul li" ).eq( 4 ).after( "<br />" );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AFdtz/)